# how to load json and extract into separate nodes in neo4j

Tags: json, neo4j, load

i'm newbie in neo4j and need help with my case...
i'm trying to load json file with the structure (updated by suggested) like below and extract into 3 nodes (big5_personality, personality_result & personality)

```
{
   "big5_personality":[
      {
         "user_name":"Satu' Roy Nababan",
         "preference":"MRT Jakarta",
         "user_name_link":"https://www.facebook.com/satu.nababan",
         "post_text_id":"[ \"was there,Berangkat kerja gelap pulang gelap selama 49 hari berturut-turut sebelum cuti 14 hari.,.,.,Tempat pertama belajar health and safety sbg seorang pefesional. Salah satu perusahaan dgn safety management system terbaik yg pernah saya temui.? See More\", \"Old normal: dominasi big four (Peter Gade, Lee Chong Wei, Taufik Hidayat, dan Lin Dan) akhirnya benar2 berakhir. Semuanya sudah pensiun.,New normal: saatnya para rising star memperebutkan dominasi atau membuat formasi big four versi new normal. Mereka yang sangat potensial saat ini; Kento Momota, Chou Thien Chen, Viktor Axelsen, Anders Antonsen, Anthony Ginting, Jonathan Christie, Lee Zii Jia.,#LinDan,#SuperDan,#Legend,#TwoT? See More\", \"#MenjemputRezeki Seri-4.,Ini adalah shipment ke-4 #Jengkiers dari Tanjung Balai ke Jakarta. Mumpung masih fresh dan stock ready lengkap, yuk mainkan!,#AyoMakanIkan,#I? See More\", \"The best version of Sabine Lisicki\", \"Naik #MRTTetapAman\", \"Terima kasih #MRTTetapAman\", \"#Jengkiers is back!,Kita kedatangan bbrp varian baru loh, seperti gabus asin, kerang, jengki putih belah, dll. Sok atuh langsung cek gambar yak, lengkap dengan PL dan kontaknya,#AyoMakanIkan,#IkanAsliTanjungBalai\", \"#CeritaGuruDiAtasGaris,#KakLiss,#GuruMantul\", \"Nih satu geng cuma bertiga doang sih, di WAG chatnya ngegas terus, ketemuan ngomongnya juga ga kalah ngegasss, tapi tetep aja pen ketemuan mulu meski banyakan dramanya utk cari jadwal yg pas,Thank you chit chat dan traktirannya woiii, enak bgt itu po*k nya, pen pesan lagi ah kapan2,#GroupHolanH,#Nama? See More\", \"Coming up next, Aldila Sutjiadi / Priska Madelyn Nugroho vs Jessy Rompies / Rifanty Dwi Kahfiani #ayotenis\", \"Beberapa cara lain menikmati produk #Jengkiers, bisa jadi nasi goreng teri medan atau mie gomak udang manis (slide 2-3),*monmaap klo teri dan udangnya ga terlalu terlihat, krn emang dikit aja ditaronya, klo kebanyakan rugi pedagang percaya ajalah disitu ada udang dan teri pokoknya,#AyoMakanIkan,#Ika? See More\", \"Thank you, Abang John Evendy Hutabarat utk waktunya, utk berbagi cerita dan pelajaran setelah sekian tahun ga ketemu secara fisik.\", \"Next match double antara duo punggawa Fed Cup ( Priska Madelyn Nugroho / Janice Tjen) vs petenis berpengalaman, Beatrice Gumulya duet dgn juniornya, Rifanty Dwi Kahfiani. Selamat menyaksikan,#ayotenis,#indonesiantennis\", \"Women single final antara 2 terbaik dalam babak round robin pekan lalu, Aldila Sutjiadi vs Jessy Rompies,#ayotenis,#indonesiantennis\", \"Here we go,Paket2 yg siap meluncur ke alamat para costumer setia #Jengkiers,Yuk j? See More\", \"Barang baru datang guys, unit ready pengiriman besok sore,Ada yg baru nih, terasi spesial, asli, didatangkan langsung dari Tg Balai, buat kalian penggemar sambal terasi sudah tentu tak mau kelewatan kan?\", \"INOVASI\", \"Federer's shots\", \"RIP Ibu Josephine Mekel (Ibunda Vokalis Once Mekel, Alumni UI, FH'89). Turut berdukacita utk Bung Once dan keluarga besar Mekel-Cambey.,Tadi malam utk pertama kalinya menghadiri acara kebaktian penghiburan sejak masa pandemik, tentu dgn protok kesehatan yg sangat ketat, jumlah yg hadir dibatasi termasuk kita yang nyanyi cuma berlima saja.\", \"Bagi yg sudah lama ga mampir kawasan MRT Dukuh Atas, nih ada yg baru loh,Totem terpasang dibanyak titik, serasa di luar negeri bukan?,#MRTJakarta\" ]",
         "post_text_eng":"[ \"was there, leaving for dark work went home dark for 49 consecutive days before taking 14 days off ..., the first place to learn health and safety as a professional. One of the companies with the best safety management system I have ever met.? See More \", \"Old normal: the dominance of the big four (Peter Gade, Lee Chong Wei, Taufik Hidayat, and Lin Dan) has finally come to an end. Everything is retired., New normal: it's time for the rising stars to fight for domination or make a new version of the Big Four formation. with very potential right now: Kento Momota, Chou Thien Chen, Viktor Axelsen, Anders Antonsen, Anthony Ginting, Jonathan Christie, Lee Zii Jia., # LinDan, # SuperDan, # Legend, # TwoT? See More \", \"#Pick up the 4th Series Rezeki., This is the 4th shipment #Jengkiers from Tanjung Balai to Jakarta. While it's still fresh and ready stock, let's play!, # Come on Eat, # I? See More\", \"The best version of Sabine Lisicki\", \"Ride #MRTKeep Safe\", \"Thank you #MRTKeep Safe\", \"#Jengkiers is back !, We have a number of new variants, such as salted cork, clams, white jengki split, etc. Sok directly check yak pictures, complete with PL and contacts, # Come on Eat, # Ikan AsliTanjungBalai\", \"# Stories of Teachers On Top of Line, # KakLiss, # Teachers Bounce\", \"Here, one gang is only the three of them, on WAG chat, it keeps on firing, meeting and talking isn't too bad, but still just finding it, even though most of the drama is to find the right schedule, Thank you chit chat and treats wow, how nice is that po * Please, order again sometime, # GroupHolanH, # Name? See More \", \"Coming up next, Aldila Sutjiadi / Priska Madelyn Nugroho vs Jessy Rompies / Rifanty Dwi Kahfiani #ayotenis\", \"Some other ways to enjoy #Jengkiers products, can be Medan teri fried rice or sweet shrimp gomak noodles (slides 2-3), * monmaap if the anchovies and the shrimp are not too visible, because it is only a little in the menu, if most of the traders lose trust there there are shrimp and anchovies, \\\"Let's Eat, # Ika? See More\", \"Thank you, Brother John Evendy Hutabarat for his time, to share stories and lessons after years of not meeting him physically.\" \"Next match doubles between Fed Cup retainer duo (Priska Madelyn Nugroho / Janice Tjen) vs. experienced tennis player, Beatrice Gumulya duet with her junior, Rifanty Dwi Kahfiani. Happy watching, # ayotenis, # indonesiantennis\", \"Women singles final between the 2 best in the round robin round last week, Aldila Sutjiadi vs Jessy Rompies, # ayotenis, # indonesiantennis\", \"Here we go, Paket2 are ready to slide to the address of loyal customers # Jengkiers, let's see?\" More, \"New goods are coming, guys, the unit is ready for delivery tomorrow afternoon. There are new ones, special shrimp paste, original, imported directly from Tg Balai, for you fans of terasi sauce, of course you don't want to go too far right?\", \"INNOVATION\", \"Federer's shots\", \"RIP Mrs. Josephine Mekel (Mother of Vocalist Once Mekel, UI Alumni, FH'89). Also sorrowing for Bung Once and the Mekel-Cambey extended family, last night for the first time attending consolation conventions since the pandemic, of course with health protection very strict, the number of attendees is limited including those of us who sing only five of them. \", \"For those who haven't stopped in the Dukuh Atas MRT area, there are new ones, Totem is installed at many points, feels like overseas, right? # MRTJakarta\" ]",
         "personality_result":[
            {
               "user_name_link":"https://www.facebook.com/satu.nababan",
               "word_count":472,
               "word_count_message":"There were 472 words in the input. We need a minimum of 600, preferably 1,200 or more, to compute statistically significant estimates",
               "processed_language":"en",
               "personality":[
                  {
                     "trait_id":"big5_openness",
                     "name":"Openness",
                     "category":"personality",
                     "percentile":0.029368278774753065,
                     "raw_score":0.6883050000463327,
                     "significant":true,
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_adventurousness",
                           "name":"Adventurousness",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.3272995424004471,
                           "raw_score":0.4889059610578305,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_artistic_interests",
                           "name":"Artistic interests",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.48276246519083293,
                           "raw_score":0.6631367244448523,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_emotionality",
                           "name":"Emotionality",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.4573453643547154,
                           "raw_score":0.6438277579254967,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_imagination",
                           "name":"Imagination",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.5606034995849714,
                           "raw_score":0.7424334257188285,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_intellect",
                           "name":"Intellect",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.7374704343214584,
                           "raw_score":0.6366655478430054,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_liberalism",
                           "name":"Authority-challenging",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.7808736715557572,
                           "raw_score":0.5552707231598478,
                           "significant":true
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"big5_conscientiousness",
                     "name":"Conscientiousness",
                     "category":"personality",
                     "percentile":0.22939241684474615,
                     "raw_score":0.5934971632418898,
                     "significant":true,
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_achievement_striving",
                           "name":"Achievement striving",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.2677419988694361,
                           "raw_score":0.655591077028367,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_cautiousness",
                           "name":"Cautiousness",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.40904830424778305,
                           "raw_score":0.47795518572548,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_dutifulness",
                           "name":"Dutifulness",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.164224436809277,
                           "raw_score":0.6349680810761815,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_orderliness",
                           "name":"Orderliness",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.867165384494327,
                           "raw_score":0.530616236542301,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_self_discipline",
                           "name":"Self-discipline",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.2026779873552365,
                           "raw_score":0.5310156326644194,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_self_efficacy",
                           "name":"Self-efficacy",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.3023937616129415,
                           "raw_score":0.7348991796444799,
                           "significant":true
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"big5_extraversion",
                     "name":"Extraversion",
                     "category":"personality",
                     "percentile":0.2667979477554203,
                     "raw_score":0.5232267972734429,
                     "significant":true,
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_activity_level",
                           "name":"Activity level",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.3490192324295949,
                           "raw_score":0.5205273056390818,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_assertiveness",
                           "name":"Assertiveness",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.3371249743821161,
                           "raw_score":0.6230467403390507,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_cheerfulness",
                           "name":"Cheerfulness",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.24258354512261554,
                           "raw_score":0.594713504568435,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_excitement_seeking",
                           "name":"Excitement-seeking",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.46972100101797953,
                           "raw_score":0.6003831372285343,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_friendliness",
                           "name":"Outgoing",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.29192693589475666,
                           "raw_score":0.5330152232542364,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_gregariousness",
                           "name":"Gregariousness",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.34577689008301526,
                           "raw_score":0.4329464839207155,
                           "significant":true
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"big5_agreeableness",
                     "name":"Agreeableness",
                     "category":"personality",
                     "percentile":0.2778846312783998,
                     "raw_score":0.7187775451521589,
                     "significant":true,
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_altruism",
                           "name":"Altruism",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.3340915482705341,
                           "raw_score":0.6900524000049065,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_cooperation",
                           "name":"Cooperation",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.445551905959055,
                           "raw_score":0.5711407367161474,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_modesty",
                           "name":"Modesty",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.5418929802964033,
                           "raw_score":0.4539269679292031,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_morality",
                           "name":"Uncompromising",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.3327649613483089,
                           "raw_score":0.6054136547271408,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_sympathy",
                           "name":"Sympathy",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.5776699806826077,
                           "raw_score":0.6709599083365048,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_trust",
                           "name":"Trust",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.6506691562935983,
                           "raw_score":0.6017503767590401,
                           "significant":true
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"big5_neuroticism",
                     "name":"Emotional range",
                     "category":"personality",
                     "percentile":0.012225596986201182,
                     "raw_score":0.3709704629886742,
                     "significant":true,
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_anger",
                           "name":"Fiery",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.5581412468086754,
                           "raw_score":0.5437137741013285,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_anxiety",
                           "name":"Prone to worry",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.7355932800664517,
                           "raw_score":0.6370636497177248,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_depression",
                           "name":"Melancholy",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.8073480016353904,
                           "raw_score":0.5034267686780826,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_immoderation",
                           "name":"Immoderation",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.24332416646800148,
                           "raw_score":0.47385528964341017,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_self_consciousness",
                           "name":"Self-consciousness",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.7754603650051617,
                           "raw_score":0.5865448670864387,
                           "significant":true
                        },
                        {
                           "trait_id":"facet_vulnerability",
                           "name":"Susceptible to stress",
                           "category":"personality",
                           "percentile":0.7069366679699797,
                           "raw_score":0.5023098966625577,
                           "significant":true
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "needs":[
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_challenge",
                     "name":"Challenge",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.3111815824704851,
                     "raw_score":0.7096962589081414,
                     "significant":true
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_closeness",
                     "name":"Closeness",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.35074889692132116,
                     "raw_score":0.776347669910458,
                     "significant":true
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_curiosity",
                     "name":"Curiosity",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.31319024070209367,
                     "raw_score":0.8038374100057984,
                     "significant":true
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_excitement",
                     "name":"Excitement",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.381914846033436,
                     "raw_score":0.6613380266802147,
                     "significant":true
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_harmony",
                     "name":"Harmony",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.31267505503919857,
                     "raw_score":0.7923972251247591,
                     "significant":true
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_ideal",
                     "name":"Ideal",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.3275871372890826,
                     "raw_score":0.6698318741171541,
                     "significant":true
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_liberty",
                     "name":"Liberty",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.32239839981885254,
                     "raw_score":0.7192415822205642,
                     "significant":true
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_love",
                     "name":"Love",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.3964120015403447,
                     "raw_score":0.7558832961971879,
                     "significant":true
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_practicality",
                     "name":"Practicality",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.9649293870023881,
                     "raw_score":0.7669009397738932,
                     "significant":true
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_self_expression",
                     "name":"Self-expression",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.6353593836964153,
                     "raw_score":0.6869779372404304,
                     "significant":true
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_stability",
                     "name":"Stability",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.24020391881699688,
                     "raw_score":0.711976290266912,
                     "significant":true
                  },
                  {
                     "trait_id":"need_structure",
                     "name":"Structure",
                     "category":"needs",
                     "percentile":0.5035013183383961,
                     "raw_score":0.6963163749792464,
                     "significant":true
                  }
               ],
               "warnings":[
                  {
                     "warning_id":"WORD_COUNT_MESSAGE",
                     "message":"There were 472 words in the input. We need a minimum of 600, preferably 1,200 or more, to compute statist"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "gender":"Male",
         "marital_status":"Single",
         "user_likes":"Jengkiers\r\nPriska Madelyn Nugroho\r\nMrs Laos World\r\nWimbledon\r\nKakliss MCI\r\nILUNI K3 FKM UI\r\nBadminton Vietnam\r\nBMT MEDIA\r\nTennis Indonesia\r\nRina Silvia Aritonang\r\nDina Maria Simamora\r\nIndustrial Hygiene\r\nChristopher Rungkat\r\nEffendi Hutahaean\r\nOya Yolanda Haam\r\nDigdyo Fakirul Gareng Crew\r\nShanty Sihombing\r\nPaulus Nalsali Herianto Tamba\r\nIndonesia Feminis\r\nIsna Muharyunis\r\nJoko Sumartono\r\nMRT Jakarta\r\nLagu Rohani Terbaru\r\nAldila Sutjiadi\r\nNurhalima Purba\r\nToro Prima Jaya\r\nHanif Optik Citra\r\nDarus Harjuniadi\r\nAtika Sumco\r\nMuhamad Yusuf Lamba\r\nMadinisafety Const\r\nRiri Gpp\r\nBethanie Mattek-Sands\r\nPenyet Everest\r\nSteve Harvey\r\nChoir \"Alumni Kristiani UI\"\r\nMartina Hingis\r\nGenie Bouchard\r\nBelinda Bencic\r\nLaLiga\r\nDr. Suryo Bawono, Sp.OG\r\nJoyful Choir Cibubur\r\nIMPORTIR.ORG\r\nIrwan Wahyudiono\r\nArdantya Syahreza\r\nBubuk Silky Puding\r\nEnglish For All Indonesian\r\nIIEF EduFair\r\nTAR Team BP Tangguh West Papua\r\nKang H Idea",
         "location":"Depok",
         "age_range":"31-35",
         "education":"Bachelor"
      }
   ]
}
```

i've tried to using this command, and successfully to create a node labeled big5_personality, but get stuck with 2 others.

```
WITH "///big5_personality.json" AS file
call apoc.load.json(file) YIELD value
unwind value.big5_personality as item
merge (a:big5_personality{user_name_link: item.user_name_link})
on create set
a.user_name = item.user_name,
a.preference = item.preferance,
a.gender = item.gender,
a.marital_status = item.marital_status,
a.education = item.education,
a.age_range = item.age_range,
a.location = item.location,
a.user_likes = item.user_likes,
a.post_text_id = item.post_text_id,
a.post_text_eng = item.post_text_eng,
a.identity = item.identity

foreach (personality_result in item.personality_result |
merge (b:personality_result {user_name_link: item.user_name_link})
on create set 
b.word_count = personality_result.word_count,
b.word_count_message = personality_result.word_count_message,
b.processed_language = personality_result.processed_language
) 
merge (a)-[r1:rel_personality_result]->(b)

foreach (personality in item.personality_result.personality |
merge (c:personality {user_name_link: b.user_name_link})
on create set 
c.trait_id = personality.trait_id
MERGE (b)<-[:rel_personality]-(c)
)
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues with your data file. Among them are:

1. Your Cypher code expects `personality_result` to be a *list* of JSON objects. It is not.

   (a) It is a single string, not a list.

   (b) That string seems to consist of the *truncated start* of a **stringified** JSON object (that includes a lot of extra pretty-printing whitespace).

   So, everything in your Cypher query starting at the `FOREACH` will not work.
2. In your next-to-last `MERGE`, `personality_result.personality` should probably be just `personality`.

You may have other issues, but it is hard to tell until you fix your data file and code.

Comment: thanks for your quick respong @cybersam, i'll try to fix the data first then

Comment: json and cypher updated, please help me... when i run my query then raise error Type mismatch: expected a map but was List

Comment: hi, i've found solution for my case. by adding unwind item.personality_result as itema unwind itema.personality as itemb after line unwind value.big5_personality as item. but there's onlly 4 nodes created for personality label.WITH "///big5_personality.json" AS file
call apoc.load.json(file) YIELD value
unwind value.big5_personality as item
unwind item.personality_result as itema
unwind itema.personality as itemb
return distinct itemb.name,
there's 5 records, ("Openness"
"Conscientiousness"
"Extraversion"
"Agreeableness"
"Emotional range") should be 20 recs created, any suggestion?

Comment: In your updated data file `personality` only has 5 elements, not 20.

Comment: yes, my fault, there's only 5... but it's still only 1 element created not 5... can you tell me what wrong with my command

Answer (score -1):

i found the solution for my problem... maybe it's dirty way and there's better solution for my case... the updated code is below :

```
WITH "///big5_personality.json" AS file
call apoc.load.json(file) YIELD value
unwind value.big5_personality as item
unwind item.personality_result as itema
unwind itema.personality_detail as itemb
UNWIND itemb.children as itemc
merge (a:big5_personality{user_name_link: item.user_name_link})
on create set
a.user_name = item.user_name,
a.preference = item.preferance,
a.gender = item.gender,
a.marital_status = item.marital_status,
a.education = item.education,
a.age_range = item.age_range,
a.location = item.location,
a.user_likes = item.user_likes,
a.post_text_id = item.post_text_id,
a.post_text_eng = item.post_text_eng,
a.identity = item.identity

foreach (personality_result in itema |
merge (b:personality_result {user_name_link: item.user_name_link})
on create set 
b.word_count = personality_result.word_count,
b.word_count_message = personality_result.word_count_message,
b.processed_language = personality_result.processed_language
) 
merge (a)-[r1:rel_big5_personality_result{user_name_link: a.user_name_link, word_count: itema.word_count, word_count_message: itema.word_count_message, processed_language: itema.processed_language}]->(b)

foreach (trait in itemb |
merge (c:personality{user_name_link : item.user_name_link, trait_id: trait.trait_id, trait_name: trait.name, trait_category: trait.category, trait_percentile: trait.percentile,  trait_significant: trait.significant})
ON CREATE SET
c.trait_raw_score = trait.raw_score
MERGE (b)-[:rel_personality_result{user_name_link : itema.user_name_link, trait_id: itemb.trait_id, trait_name: itemb.name, trait_category: itemb.category, trait_percentile: itemb.percentile, trait_significant: itemb.significant}]->(c)
)

FOREACH (facet IN itemc |
MERGE (d:personality_children{user_name_link : itema.user_name_link, personality_trait_id: itemb.trait_id})
ON CREATE SET
d.facet_trait_id = facet.trait_id,
d.facet_name = facet.name,
d.facet_category = facet.category,
d.facet_percentile = facet.percentile,
d.facet_significant = facet.significant
MERGE (c)-[:rel_personality_children{user_name_link : itema.user_name_link, personality_trait_id: itemb.trait_id, facet_trait_id: itemc.trait_id, facet_name: itemc.name, facet_category: itemc.category, facet_percentile: itemc.percentile, facet_significant: itemc.significant}]->(d)
)
```